# Why has this suggest-edit been rejected, but the proposed changes were mostly applied?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33719206) was rejected. However, most of its proposed changes have been applied to the post.

### Suggest edit

Suggest edit comment:

> Added missing tag*; Added text for the symbols ?: to make the question
> easier to find; Shortend question & title

[image]

### Actual edit

Actual edit comment:

> Added key words for easier searching

[image]

As far as I can see, the suggest-edit should have been approved or approved & edited. What am I missing?

<sub>* The added tag turned out to be a synonym for an already existing, therefore not visible.</sub>

See [question-timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6259982/timeline#history_8ef1ad98-d4e9-45a9-a99c-8568a2605821).

Comment: Pet peeve: "[**Don't include tags in the title**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: @Larnu has the correct reason, but IMO this definitely should have been a "accept and improve" rather than a "reject and edit".

Comment: "What am I missing?" - nothing, just the fact that you're dealing with human beings. I'm sure there are people out there who hit reject and edit on anything that is more than a missed typo. There is really no standard for how strict people are.

Comment: I sometimes use "Reject and Edit" in a similar way when someone suggests an otherwise good edit but that adds code formatting to random keywords. But when I do, I usually ping the user in a comment explaining that code formatting is reserved for code, to make it absolutely clear why I rejected their edit and what they should be doing differently. In this particular case I would have chosen "Improve" though, but I guess everyone has different things they find particularly annoying.

Comment: Also about the code formatting in this particular case, I don't think they should have removed the code formatting from `?:`. While I find it very annoying when code formatting is used on something that *isn't* code, `?:` *is* code so it's perfectly OK to format it as such.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It was rejected because you're **not** supposed to include tags in the title when written in a way that's tag-like. In fact, when a tag is not used as a natural-English part of the title, it should be edited out. The help center, in "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" says:

> - **Don't include tags in the title**. The system will automatically prepend the most important tag to your title for search-engine optimization purposes. You don't need to (and shouldn't) do it manually. If you want to include the name of the language/library/framework/tool, do it in regular English, not as a bracketed tag.

If your suggested edit hadn't been rejected, this issue with your edits wouldn't have been brought to your attention. Without it being brought to your attention, you wouldn't have been able to learn that the edits which you've been suggesting should be a bit different in order to be in sync with the standards of the site. Given that you didn't handle this specific issue correctly in 6 of your last 10 suggested edits, it's something that really did need to be brought to your attention.

Unfortunately, at this point, we don't have a way within the edit system to reject a suggested edit using a custom reason, to actually explain such issues, while also applying an edit to the post without having to wait for the review of the suggested edit to be complete. We used to have the capability to reject an edit with a custom reason that *very briefly* (due to limited characters) explained the actual reason(s) for rejecting the edit and then to apply an edit that could demonstrate what the edit should have been. Personally, I found having that capability quite helpful in communicating to editors what the issues were with the edit (or at least attempting to communicate to the editor, as such reasons are only shown to editors if the editor goes and looks for the information).

Comment: A custom reject reason would be quite helpful indeed.

Comment: There is a feature request [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123718/349538) asking for allowing custom rejection reasons when rejecting and editing.